# css select child if other child has an image

Tags: css, siblings

I've got some div elements that show up next to each other.

```
<div class="parentdiv">
    <div class="article-teaser-text2">
            some text ...<a href="http://example.com">Lees meer</a>      
    </div>
    <div class="article-teaser-image">
            <img src="somimage.png" >      
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to make the first div wider if the second div doesn't contain a image

is it posible to select the `div.article-teaser-text2` if `div.article-teaser-image > img`

I thought something like:

```
div.article-teaser-image > img ~ div.article-teaser-text2
```

but that would select the `div.article-teaser-text2` if it was a sibling of `img` if I'm not mistaken.

I know I can do this is jQuery but I'm looking for a CSS solution

Answer (score 0):

No. The current specs do not have such a selector and for good reason. Consider this analogy.

As humans we inherit the traits of our parents - skin color, eye color, height and a multitude of other phyical attributes. Now we are free to override some or all of these traits but we may **never** define our parents' trait.

Take this analogy to CSS and understand that children elements should never define the characteristics of the parent.

Applying this strategy there is a solution.

```
<div class="parentdiv HASimage">
    <div class="article-teaser-text2">
            some text ...<a href="http://example.com">Lees meer</a>      
    </div>
    <div class="article-teaser-image">
            <img src="somimage.png" >      
    </div>
</div>
```

Notice how I added the class "HASimage". Add a specific class to the parent to differentiate whether or not a child has an image. This can be easily be done with PHP or any server side language. In css then do the following:

```
.parentdiv .article-teaser-image {
     normal traits (without image)
}
.parentdiv.HASiamge .article-teaser-image {
     override traits and add extra traits (with image)
}
```

Hope that pushes you in the right direction.

Regards.

Comment: CSS selectors are not humans. And we, the humans, need the parent CSS selector :(

Comment: yes but the problem is that I want to do this doing CSS. If i need to add to a class to the parent div I might as wel change the html output so I get 2 different html views.

Comment: The reasons such selector is not supported is far and wide - quoted by leading developer of WebKit: "With parent selectors it becomes extremely easy to accidentally cause a document-wide grovel. People can and will misuse this selector. Supporting it is giving people a whole lot of rope to hang themselves with."

Comment: note: I'm not looking for a way to change a parent. I'm looking for a way to change a sibling which is supported. Changing the sibling on the condition of the inside of current element. But maybe that's just my perspective...

Comment: "Change the sibling on the condition of the inside of current element" - you still need to track up the dom tree thus requiring a parent selector. This can not be done in CSS. You can easily do this in Jquery but you already know how